# finding ldd search path

Tags: linux, share, libraries

How can I find the search path of `ldd`? Assume `ldd` returns

```
[mahmood@dhcppc2 bin]$ ldd /home/mahmood/amd64-linux/lib/scsi-bus.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffc27c7000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ffb13a25000)
        libstdc++.so.5 => not found
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007ffb137a0000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ffb13589000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffb131f6000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000037d6000000)
```

I want to know what is the default location for `ldd`? I mean `/lib64` or `/usr/lib` or `/usr/lib64` ....?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The **ldconfig** command will show these paths for you...

```
ldconfig -v | grep -v ^$'\t'
```

The paths are set in `/etc/ld.so.conf` and `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`.

Comment: I need to run it with sudo

Answer (score 3):

Usually this is set on `/etc/ld.so.conf`